# How do I vertically align these containers with flexbox?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to align the `.header-container` and `.title-container` the same vertically along the page. Currently, the `.header-container` is oriented using `justify-content: space-around` and it works exactly how I want (i.e. there is equal spacing on both sides of the items within this container and equal spacing between the items; **also, when the window is downsized the items do not squish together but rather maintain this orientation**).

The `title-container` does not behave the same way when applying the same instruction `justify-content: space-around`. In fact, it doesn't move at all when I apply it and I cannot figure out why.

How can I align the items in `.title-container` vertically so that they copy the same orientation of the items in `.header-container`? Here is a [link](https://cdn.statically.io/gh/TheOdinProject/curriculum/81a5d553f4073e593d23a6ab00d50eef8620796d/foundations/html_css/project/imgs/01.png) to an example of what I am trying to achieve (see the dark blue area at the top of the image; see how the outer edges of the items all fall in line vertically? This is what I'm going for but cannot figure it out).

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  background: #1F2937;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 0px 64px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #F9FAF8;
}

.link-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  gap: 24px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #E5E7EB;
}

.title-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.title {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #F9FAF8;
}

.title-info {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #E5E7EB;
}

.image1-container {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="logo">Header Logo</div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <div class="link1">Link 1</div>
      <div class="link2">Link 2</div>
      <div class="link3">Link 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="title-container">
    <div class="title">Website Title, This Site is Awesome!
      <div class="title-info">This is where I would put my info... If I had some!</div>
      <button class="button1">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image1-container">
      <div class="image1">This is a placeholder for an image...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex elements size will be equal to their children by default. Better to not trust them in this situation. Using fixed sizes will help. You can use `width` and `margin: 0 auto` properties to achieve this. It's most practical way to make it.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container header">
  <div class="logo">Logo</div>
  <div class="navigation">
    <span>Menu 1</span>
    <span>Menu 2</span>
    <span>Menu 3</span>
    <span>Menu 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container title">
  <div class="title-info">
    This is title info
  </div>
</div>
```